# Skip dialog when excel starts from batch

Tags: excel, batch-file

I have made a batch script which start my macro in personal.xlsb. The problem is that if I already have excel open, the workbook should be open in read only because then personal.xlsb is open and hence can not be open in write mode. The problem is that I can not get excel to skip all that dialog message saying do you want to open it as read only, notify or cancel. What am I doing wrong?

```
echo "Launch excel"
Set ExcelArgs=CREO

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE16\Excel.exe" /r /e "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB" 

exit 0
```

Comment: Using Excel 14 /r it works for me with an xlsx file without macro.

Comment: The problem i think is due to personal.xlsb which always get loaded. I am working on a different approach now. Instead of opening the user personal.xlsb i then open the source one at the server. Most likely two user would not accsess this one at the same and then there should not be any issue. Thanks for helping though